# python execute shell command with wildchar in path

Tags: python, regex, shell, path

```
ls 
[cc]a.txt bba.txt [cc]b.txt bbb.txt

ipython

glob.glob("[cc]*")
[]
glob.glob("bb*")
['bba.txt','bbb.txt']
glob.glob("[bb]*")
['bba.txt','bbb.txt']
```

How can get `[cc]a.txt` and `[cc]b.txt` match ?  The char `[` in the `[bb]*` seem to make no sense . use like :

```
glob.glob("\[cc\]*")
[]
```

also is NULL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

enclose `[` and `]` in `[]`.

bash:

```
test $ ls
[cc]a.txt test.dat  test.gp   test.py
```

python:

```
>>> glob.glob(r'[[]cc[]]*.txt') #yuck ...
['[cc]a.txt']
```

In terms of globbing, `[ something]` means match any of the characters between the square brackets.  so `[cc]*.txt` is equivalent to `c*.txt` which isn't what you want.

Of course, a more robust solution is to stop naming files with glob characters in them ;^).

Comment: if not use glob.glob . How can use other method can sample use '[' to match ?

Comment: @yanxinyou -- I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  If you're looking for different options, You can use `os.listdir` and filter the results based on a hand-rolled regular expression ...

Comment: thankyou . I want to use [somethins]* to match some files .Then to move it . I use  [[] replace [ , and []] to ] . It works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot simply escape the *, ?, [, ] characters. Confer http://bugs.python.org/issue8402:

> The documentation for fnmatch.translate, which is what ultimately gets
>   called, says:    There is no way to quote meta-characters. Sorry.

The solution is more complicated, as explained by mgilson.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for tracking down the documentation on this. (+1)